# How to create a read more link in Drupal views?

Tags: drupal, content-management-system

I am facing a problem in drupal views, i want to show the node body 400 character and add a read more link on after trimming. So I have trimmed the node body 400 character and put the "More link: Yes" on views. I can see the ellipsis(... after words) but not showing the link. What is the procedure to add a read more link? I am using drupal 6.22 version

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try the [Read More Link module](http://drupal.org/project/read_more)

Answer (score 2):

A More link set to yes will send a user to a page view of that view. My typical approach to the more link is to add a field to the view for path. Then I set the path to be rewritten as `<a href="[path]">More &raquo;</a>`.

Having the path field a the end of the view (Or at least after your body field) will give you the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I had done it.

In the `edit` of my view, I added a field `node:link`. 
Then I removed the Label and left it empty and added "Read more" in `Text to display` 
I checked the checkbox `Trim this field to a maximum length`, entered my maximum length in the textfield and checked the `Add an ellipsis` and `Trim only on a word boundary` options.

Click on Update button and save the changes. You are done!

Comment: This method works for fields that have text values. But does not work for fields with multiple taxonomy terms.